# Have I phrased this sentence correctly?

Tags: grammar

(With reference to a poll.)

> He got ten times as many as negative votes as positive ones.

Have I framed this sentence correctly?

Comment: The middle 'as' is *de trop*. Only judges sentence by the way. We phrase or construct.

Comment: Vaibhav, I took the liberty of formatting your question a little bit. Sometimes it can be hard to figure out how to get a new line! You can read about some of these tricks at [this question](http://meta.ell.stackexchange.com/questions/996), which explains the "two blank spaces" trick. Welcome aboard.

Answer (score 1):

Almost, you have an extra "as" in between "many" and "negative".

"He got ten times as many negative votes as positive ones." would be ok.

If you wanted it to be a bit more formal , you could say "He received ten times as many negative votes as positive ones."